# SQLite Error disk I/O when running Airflow commands

Tags: sqlite, airflow, airflow-scheduler

Upon running:
`airflow scheduler`

I get the following error:

```
[2022-08-10 13:26:53,501] {scheduler_job.py:708} INFO - Starting the scheduler
[2022-08-10 13:26:53,502] {scheduler_job.py:713} INFO - Processing each file at most -1 times
[2022-08-10 13:26:53,509] {executor_loader.py:105} INFO - Loaded executor: SequentialExecutor
[2022-08-10 13:26:53 -0400] [1388] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2022-08-10 13:26:53,540] {manager.py:160} INFO - Launched DagFileProcessorManager with pid: 1389
[2022-08-10 13:26:53,545] {scheduler_job.py:1233} INFO - Resetting orphaned tasks for active dag runs
. 
. 
. 
[2022-08-10 13:26:53 -0400] [1391] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 1391
Process DagFileProcessor10-Process:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dromo/anaconda3/envs/airflow_env_2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 998, in _commit_impl
    self.engine.dialect.do_commit(self.connection)
  File "/home/dromo/anaconda3/envs/airflow_env_2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 672, in do_commit
    dbapi_connection.commit()
sqlite3.OperationalError: disk I/O error
```

I get this 'disk I/O error' as well when I run `airflow webserver --port 8080` command as so:

```
Workers: 4 sync
Host: 0.0.0.0:8080
Timeout: 120
Logfiles: - -
Access Logformat:
=================================================================
[2022-08-10 14:42:28 -0400] [2759] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2022-08-10 14:42:29 -0400] [2759] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8080 (2759)
[2022-08-10 14:42:29 -0400] [2759] [INFO] Using worker: sync
.
.
.
[2022-08-10 14:42:55,149] {app.py:1455} ERROR - Exception on /static/appbuilder/datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.css [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dromo/anaconda3/envs/airflow_env_2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 998, in _commit_impl
    self.engine.dialect.do_commit(self.connection)
  File "/home/dromo/anaconda3/envs/airflow_env_2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 672, in do_commit
    dbapi_connection.commit()
sqlite3.OperationalError: disk I/O error
```

Any ideas as to what might be causing this and possible fixes?

Comment: I am also running on WSL Version 1 and am using the default SQLite for Airflow database.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like airflow doesn't find the database on the disk, try to initialize it:

```bash
airflow db init
```

Comment: Hey! I tried it and still see the error. `airflow db init` followed by `airflow scheduler`

Comment: I got around this by switching over from sqlite database (default one) to postgresql database. This is the guide I followed: https://medium.com/geekculture/apache-airflow-2-0-complete-installation-with-wsl-explained-71a65d509aba

Comment: @DianaVazquezRomo it worked after following that tutorial for me too - I was getting the same error and `airflow db init` did not work either.